# spark streaming + querying hive table in every streaming batch?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a Spark Streaming application recieving data from flume and after some transformations it writes on Hbase.

But to make those transformations i need to query some data from a hive table. Then the problem starts.

I can't use sqlContext or hiveContext inside the transformations (they are not serializable) and when i write the code outside of the transformation it runs only once.

How do i do to make this code run in every streaming batch?

```
  def TB_PARAMETRIZACAO_TGC(sqlContext: HiveContext): Map[String,(String,String)] = {
  val df_consulta = sqlContext.sql("SELECT TGC,TIPO,DESCRICAO FROM dl_prepago.TB_PARAMETRIZACAO_TGC")
  val resultado = df_consulta.map(x => x(Consulta_TB_PARAMETRIZACAO_TGC.TGC.id).toString
      -> (x(Consulta_TB_PARAMETRIZACAO_TGC.TIPO.id).toString, x(Consulta_TB_PARAMETRIZACAO_TGC.DESCRICAO.id).toString)).collectAsMap()
  resultado
}
```

Comment: Did the answer help BTW?

Answer (score 1):

Try this very simple approach below, noting that static JOIN tables could be cached and that they should not be too big, otherwise that static would need to be KV Store LKP, say Hbase:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.OutputMode

object StreamJoinStatic {

case class Sales(
  transactionId: String,
  customerId:    String,
  itemId:        String,
  amountPaid:    Double)

case class Customer(customerId: String, customerName: String)

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
 val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder
   .master("local") // Not recommended
   .appName("exampleStaticJoinStrStr")
   .getOrCreate()

//create stream from socket
val socketStreamDf = sparkSession.readStream
  .format("socket")
  .option("host", "localhost")
  .option("port", 50050)
  .load()

import sparkSession.implicits._
//take customer data as static df from where ever
val customerDs = sparkSession.read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", true)
  .load("src/main/resources/customers.csv")
  .as[Customer]

import sparkSession.implicits._
val dataDf = socketStreamDf.as[String].flatMap(value ? value.split(" "))
val salesDs = dataDf
  .as[String]
  .map(value ? {
    val values = value.split(",")
    Sales(values(0), values(1), values(2), values(3).toDouble)
  })

val joinedDs = salesDs.join(customerDs, "customerId")

val query = joinedDs.writeStream.format("console").outputMode(OutputMode.Append())

query.start().awaitTermination()
}
}
```

Then adapt to your specific situation.